# how to check out files from Repo of Azure DevOps in Edge

Tags: tfvc, azure-devops-server

I installed Azure DevOps on my Windows Server and made a Team Foundation repository.
We used to use it in Visual Studio, but in my new project We decided to use it in Edge.
However, DevOps Repo seems that it does not support check-out in case of web browser, only check-in is allowed.
Is check-out not supported in browser usage?

We want to check out files from Repo in browser.

Comment: I'd highly recommend switching back to using VS (or another git system). Developers should be checking out code to their local machine, making changes and pushing up. Doing it in Edge is not going to work out well for the team

Comment: I am really wondering why anyone would want to use an upload/download strategybiver using a 'real client'. Especially since there is an explorer integration available too, which will tell you manage the files from Windows Explorer.

Comment: The other thing I'd investigate is whether Git would be a better fit. TFVC is quite antiquated compared to Git. And Microsoft has done minimal investments in its ecosystem.

Comment: @Yoshihide Suga Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid that you couldn’t use check-out directly in web browser.

But you can click the `Download as  Zip` to download repo in your local and make changes and click the `Upload file(s)` to check in.

[image: download and upload files]

I think that the Team Explorer in Visual Studio or TFVC command are recommended way to manage your codes and files. Please refer to doc:[check out and edit files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/check-out-edit-files?view=azure-devops)